# what is DirEncryptConnector?

Tags: android

When I run my application I get frosen some operation. I get logs. But there is nothing form my app but there are many times same logs:

```
01-22 11:58:32.085   562   562 D STATUSBAR-NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false 
01-22 11:58:33.695   458   512 E DirEncryptConnector: Communications error: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory 
01-22 11:58:33.695   458   512 E DirEncryptConnector: Error in NativeDaemonConnector:    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory 
01-22 11:58:34.105   562   562 D STATUSBAR-NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster: data=0  bt=false
```

What is DirEncryptConnector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more details, take a look here, is the Android source code:
http://gitorious.org/ginger/frameworks-base/blobs/2435a927f30efe38c673bfaed64a9880028da9e8/services/java/com/android/server/NativeDaemonConnector.java

Inside, you can se when those logs are written, for example, you have

```
log.e(TAG, "Error in NativeDaemonConnector", e);
```

on line 85.